# Android perform a task when CPU is asleep

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, handler, background-process, wakelock

I need to send GPS data to a web service every "X" minutes, so far I've tried using a BroadcastReceiver and a timer with a handler but both fail once I lock the screen (CPU enters sleep mode).

How can I force the phone to do my task every "X" time even when asleep?

The GPS implementation and permissions I already have it solved I'm only missing the communication with the WS when the phone is asleep. I also tried using WakefulBroadcastReceiver but it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JobIntentService and JobSchedular